# How should I use a certificate with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, windows-10, certificate, httpclient

I need to use a web API from one of our partners. Their API require that I use a certificate to connect.

I do not want to install the certificate on our servers (VMs). That is counterproductive to our phoenix server strategy.

I try to use the certificate programmatically. The problem is that I get an error:

> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I create my `HttpClient` using this code:

```
_certificate = new X509Certificate2(_certificateFile);
var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(_certificate);
var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(_url) };
```

I can make it work by overriding certificate validations:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };
```

But that looks like poor style.

I have verified that my endpoint matches CN in the certificate

Is the `AuthenticationException` simply because certificate is not installed in the certificate store?

If yes, can I temporarily with code install the certificate and remove it after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The remote certificate is invalid" indicates that .NET Framework thinks the server side certificate of your partner's web service is invalid (quite normal if you don't have necessary root/intermediate certificates installed).

You can suppress the default check by changing `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`, but you should implement your own to make sure you do validate their certificate in a reasonable way to avoid attacks.

You should also use `HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`, so that your custom validator only takes effect in the scope of this specific `HttpClient` instance, but does not affect elsewhere in your app,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.servercertificatecustomvalidationcallback?view=netframework-4.8

However, the certificate they gave you (usually a client certificate) is validated by their web service, not locally on your machine.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea how to validate the servers certificate? Do you have any pointers how to get started with that? Or is it possible get more information on what .net thinks is invalid about the certificate?

Comment: @TorbenNielsen the Microsoft engineer working on that area wrote an answer already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57755028/how-to-validate-a-ssl-certificate-with-c-sharp