# FtpWebRequest EnableSsl = true ERROR 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure3

Tags: c#, .net-core, ftpwebrequest

I try to connect to an ftp server over ssl with the ftpwebrequest class by activating the Enabled option ssl = true the enough error is shown

> **The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.**

THIS IS MY CODE

```
public void Upload(string container, string fileName, byte[] b)
        {
            Uri fullUri = new Uri(string.Format(@"{0}/{1}/{2}", Host, container, fileName));
            FtpWebRequest ftps = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(fullUri);
            ftps.Credentials = GetCredentials();

            ftps.KeepAlive = false;
            ftps.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftps.UseBinary = true;
            ftps.EnableSsl = Ssl;
            ftps.ContentLength = b.Length;
            using (Stream StreamRequest = ftps.GetRequestStream())
            {
                StreamRequest.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                StreamRequest.Close();
            }
        }
```

I have seen that in some publications they use methods such as

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
```

but I don't know how correct it is or or if I have to get my certificate and give it a similar validation

Comment: 1) Do learn what is SSL/TLS and how certificates (server/client) are involved. 2) The error you got of course is due to the server certificate (on FTP server side) which is not trusted by your client side Windows system. The method you saw is just a common hack to blindly trust all such certificates. You should think carefully if you want to trust all, or at least do some validation.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that making all certificates valid is ... silly? Now I look for how to validate the certificate that I have been provided through the file file.crt, but it has been difficult to find concrete answers to the problem.

Comment: I have implemented the solution proposed in this blog [link](https://rstopup.com/transferencia-de-archivos-a-traves-de-ftps-ssl-tls-con-c-net.html?unapproved=1900104&moderation-hash=3b8d9e3452820dfbdf549f308df42ed5#comment-1900104) *but I had problems with the path of my file. crt*

Comment: Please learn from the Microsoft engineer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57775354/11182