# VSTO - How get the result of user accept of untrusted IMAP SSL certificate

Tags: outlook, ssl-certificate, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am working on a plugin for Outlook. When an untrusted certificate for IMAP is used, Outlook asks for confirmation in order to continue working with the server. How can I get information about whether the certificate has been confirmed by user or not in VSTO? Maybe Outlook stores it somewhere in the VSTO entities or maybe in the registry? Helps me please.

[I means this "Security warning" window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSLnZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

VSTO (nor Outlook) doesn't provide anything for that. You can use standard .net mechanisms, for example, take a look at the [How to validate a SSL certificate with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57755028/how-to-validate-a-ssl-certificate-with-c-sharp) thread.

If you're trying to validate that an HTTPS certificate is valid, `HttpWebRequest` can do that for you.

To make `HttpWebRequest` check the revocation status you need to set the global `ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true` before calling `GetResponse()`.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidationCallback;

private static bool ValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    // Since you want to be more strict than the default, reject it if anything went wrong.
    if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // If the chain didn't suppress any type of error, and revocation
    // was checked, then it's okay.
    if (chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags == X509VerificationFlags.None &&
        chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode == X509RevocationMode.Online)
    {
        return true;
    }

    X509Chain newChain = new X509Chain();
    // change any other ChainPolicy options you want.
    X509ChainElementCollection chainElements = chain.ChainElements;

    // Skip the leaf cert and stop short of the root cert.
    for (int i = 1; i < chainElements.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        newChain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(chainElements[i].Certificate);
    }

    // Use chainElements[0].Certificate since it's the right cert already
    // in X509Certificate2 form, preventing a cast or the sometimes-dangerous
    // X509Certificate2(X509Certificate) constructor.
    // If the chain build successfully it matches all our policy requests,
    // if it fails, it either failed to build (which is unlikely, since we already had one)
    // or it failed policy (like it's revoked).        
    return newChain.Build(chainElements[0].Certificate);
}
```