# Validating a JSON response from web server

Tags: c#, validation, https, invision

I am currently using the Invision forums to host my site,

We are using their API keys to pull users data & log them in via our launcher.

It's been brought to my attention that all the information returned to our launcher is in plan text (JSON). This makes it very easy for someone to redirect our traffic to the launcher and plug in a fake json file.

In short cracking the launcher/login system.

I need to know if there is any method of validation I can call to ensure that the information IS being sent from my host & not another Man in the Middle.

The site is HTTPS.

Thanks.

Comment: If the request to the API (where the JSON is returned) also is using HTTPS, and is done server-side, then it should be very difficult for anyone to do a MITM attack. We'd have to see more details of both the code, and the network architecture

Comment: @Adyson, I can confirm that our host is running HTTPS. 

On our side we are making the calls via the RestSharp lib - But issue is that when we call a GET via the url of our site, the information is returned in plan text.

To combat that we've moved to OAuth instead of API keys.

However I am still struggling to confirm validity of the returned json. Currently doing research in checking SSL certificates, Any suggestions?

Comment: "We are using their API keys to pull users data & log them in via our launcher"... Do you mean you by this that you have access to the user's data using your API key and before the user has actually authenticated? If so, that's the problem you need to fix.

Comment: Once a user has authenticated and been issued an OAuth token, the launcher code should just be concerned with confirming the token validity... Any requests to the Invision API should ideally be with the user's authority instead of your private API key

Comment: "I can confirm that our host is running HTTPS"...that wasn't what I asked. I asked if the **API** is accessed using HTTPS. When you make the request to Invision, is it done using HTTPS?

Comment: "But issue is that when we call a GET via the url of our site, the information is returned in plan text. To combat that we've moved to OAuth instead of API keys"...this makes no sense. OAuth is an authentication method. It doesn't affect the content-type of a response

Comment: But what do you mean by "call a GET via the url of our site" exactly? I thought the issue was worrying whether the data returned from Invision had been compromised? That has nothing to do with what _your_ site returns. Or at least, not on the face of it. And what is your "launcher" exactly? Are you talking about a desktop application? It's all a bit confusing, from your description. It would be better if you gave us a precise run-down of which requests are made, from where and to where, and using what authentication and security. And then tell us which one you're concerned about.

Comment: @ADyson, We're using an application on users PCs to see if they have any active licenses and launch the respective software. Originally we were doing this with an API key, This proved to be an issue when it leaked allowing people to make their own requests to the API. We've now moved to another system OAuth. However this still leaves it possible for a user to redirect traffic from their local PC to a local server and return a fake Json file. I am currently reading into [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063774/c-sharp-validating-an-x509certificate2-am-i-doing-this-right).

Comment: Ok that's a bit clearer. Yes certificate validation would make sense in this context. You could also encrypt the JSON, so it's harder to make a valid clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so a little bit of backround here.

1, We are using a cloud hosted community, so our access is a tad more limited than
a self hosted website etc.

2, We WERE sending the api key as a paramater with c#, here's a sample of how i would retrieve a users active purchases, (i would enable pageview tabs on results, which have access to download links, updaters and launch methds of programs etc) :

```
var client = new RestClient("https://HIDDEN.forumflash.com");
var request = new RestRequest("/api/nexus/purchases", DataFormat.Json);
request.AddParameter("key", "BlahBlahBlah"); // Enter in Api Key
request.AddParameter("customers", MemID); // Pass id from member request
request.AddParameter("active", 1); // Check active purchases
var response = client.Get(request);

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    dynamic resp = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
    // do stuff with object.
}
```

The result is always a json string, and I have no ability to change this.

3, Another way of us being able to access this information, is by getting an oAuth token,
and sending that instead of an api key. This I feel is a touch safer, as we can revoke any authorization token at any time, along with change the secret on a whim, And the token would expire (change) every hour or so?

But we feel that might not be quite "enough", and would like to take it one step further by "authenticating" that the response DID in fact come from the server, or server IP address instead of some middlemans server.

I have been looking into server cert validation, but all i can seem to find is ways to disable, or how to send them, nothing implicitly with examples on validation (and lets be honest, we're always still learning, this was an oopsie on our part), a simple nudge in the appropriate direction would be of immense help.